# How can I efficiently store pressed keys values in an array with SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm starting to work on a really basic 3D engine to get started with OpenGL. All the garphics are fine, and I'm now working on keyboard controls.

To to that, I implemented a class `Camera`, which holds a `activateKey(GLint)` method. It is meant to store, when a `SDL_KEYDOWN` event is received in the main loop, the value of the key pressed, doing `camera->activateKey(windowEvent.key.keysym.sym);`. For instance, when I press 'W' to go forward, the array `GLboolean keys[1024]` is going to be filled at the `SDLK_w` index with `GL_TRUE`. This will allow me to control pressed key at every loop and move the camera acordingly to the user will.

But when I press an 'exotic' key (like F9... I know, it's not *that* exotic, but it's  not a letter), and I try to store `GL_TRUE` in `keys[]` at the corresponding index, I get an access violation. I managed to find that the GLint value for F9 is `1073741890`, whereas W is `119`. So it's clearly an out of bound exception.

My question is: **Is there a more elegant way to solve my problem than controlling just before filling `keys[]` with `GL_TRUE` that the key is included in 'WSAD'? Maybe the type of the `keys[]` array is improvable?**

Comment: Translate the key (via a map) into a logical command code/button state at the earliest moment, then you can forget about keys and think of commands/game controls as soon as possible. E.g. don't think about F8 think throttle. If F8 is throttle, translate it to MYCODE_THROTTLE straight away, then forget it was ever F8. Also makes it easier to customise keyboard layout for different players/localities/keyboard types.

Comment: I'll try to do that soon, right now I managed to make it work and I skipped to something else, that I'd like to finish. But the idea is pretty good, so I'll keep you aware of my progression. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go, is to use `SDL_SCANCODE`'s instead of SDLK. Those are mapped on the QWERTY keyboard (so AZERTY owners will still have to map the controls like an QWERTY keyboard) and are a `Uint8` type, so far below 1024. Basically, one can do:

```
GLboolean keys[256];
```

and call

```
camera->activateKey(windowEvent.key.keysym.scancode);
```

to compare inside the methods to values like `SDL_SCANCODE_W`.

If someone has a more optimized answer, I'll gladly take it, because I fear compatibility issues between OS's, and keyboard types.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Ben (see comments), I would add that it's preferable to get rid of the scancodes as soon as possible; by this, I mean converting scancodes into custom program commands (like `GO_FORWARD`) and manipulating those instead. This ables a much easier handling of events and key remapping.